# Mocking Polkadot requests in Jest

Tags: polkadot-js, testing, unit-tests, mock

I'm building out some local unit tests and am trying to figure out how to mock Polkadot requests/responses. I'm trying to get [mock-socket](https://github.com/thoov/mock-socket) working, wondering if there is any documentation on using this with Polkadot JS? Or if anyone has any handy examples?

Answer (score 1):

There is not any documentation that I am aware of that specifically combines `mock-socket` and `polkadot-js-api`.

Similar mocking of requests and responses has been implemented in a few other places:

- https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-launch
- https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet

Probably some others too if you reach out to the parachain development community.